# Closing a dialog when clicking outside it in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I have a custom dialog created with the Codename One designer. It's a simple dialog with a title and 2 buttons. The dialog is shown after a button click:

```
showForm("ContactDialog", null);
```

Now I would like the dialog to hide if the user taps anywhere on the screen outside the dialog boundaries, so the user can cancel the dialog without requiring a dedicated "cancel" button. Is this possible within the Codename One framework?

For reference, the behaviour I am trying to reproduce, can be seen in the [Snapchat friend dialog](http://assets.teenvogue.com/photos/5646418142557a3113eae66a/master/pass/NotOfficial.PNG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a new instance of the Dialog and call `setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true)`, then change the way the dialog was shown.

```
Dialog dlg = (Dialog) createContainer("/theme", "ContactDialog");
dlg.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
dlg.show();
```